# how to add a column to a sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, document-library, column

I have list name students with 2 columns First Name and Last Name and has data in the list. I want to add a new column "class" to the students list. what to do in using visual studio.

Is it the right process or is there any better procedure to deal with the lists in SharePoint ??

Answer (score 1):

You can add that column directly from the Sharepoint list itself
[image]

However to add it using Visual Studio refer following code

```
using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://Web-URL"))
{
    oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

    using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
    {
        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

        /* get the SPList object by list name*/
        SPList lst = oSPWeb.Lists["student"];


      /* create a Class field */
        SPFieldText fldName = (SPFieldText)lst.Fields.CreateNewField(
                        SPFieldType.Text.ToString(), "Class");
        fldName.Required = true;
        fldName.MaxLength = 50;


       /* add the new fields to the list */
       lst.Fields.Add(fldName);

      /* finally update list */
        lst.Update();

        oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
    }

    oSPsite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create column in List without Visual Studio.

from GUI you can follow these steps:

1. In the ribbon, click the List or Library tab.
2. In the Manage Views group, click Create Column.
3. In the Name and Type section, type the name that you want for the
   column in the Column name box.
4. Under The type of information in this column is, select the type of
   information that you want to appear in the column.
5. In the Additional Column Settings section, type a description in the
   Description box to help people understand the purpose of the column
   and what data it should contain. This description is optional.

Depending on the type of column that you selected, more options may appear in the Additional Column Settings section. Select the additional settings that you want.

1. If you want the data in the column validated, click Column
   Validation to expand, and type the Formula that you want to use to
   validate the data, and type the User message that you want to
   provide users to help them type valid data. The Column Validation
   section is not available for all types of columns.
2. Click OK.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-change-or-delete-a-column-in-a-list-or-library-2b0361ae-1bd3-41a3-8329-269e5f81cfa2?CorrelationId=2e73150a-13df-4a43-b0bc-f3dff0623168&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Answer (score 0):

You can use SharePoint designer to quickly and easily add columns to a list, if you have it installed.

1. Open your site in SharePoint Designer
2. From the left click Lists and Libraries
3. Select the relevant list
4. Click Edit List Columns under the Customization section
5. From the ribbon at the top choose Add New Column